# Retrieve Object From String C#

Tags: c#, reflection, polly

I have the below mapper json file, which tells me for a given exception, which error handling policy I want to use.

```
{
  "ExceptionMappers": [
   {
     "ExceptionName": "TimeoutException",
     "ExceptionType": "Transient",
  "Policy": "WaitAndRetry",
  "WaitType": "Linear"
},
{
  "ExceptionName": "DivideByZeroException",
  "ExceptionType": "Permanent",
  "Policy": "CircuitBreaker"
},
{
  "ExceptionName": "StackOverflowException",
  "ExceptionType": "LogOnly",
  "Policy": "WaitAndRetry",
  "WaitType": "Linear"
}
]
 }
```

Then using the below code I am trying to get the type of exception and apply a policy using which the action can be called. But here I am stuck, how to get the exception type from a string name.

```
   public void Execute(Action action, string exceptionName)
    {
        var filePath = @"appsetting.json";
        var exceptionMapperJson = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filePath);
        var rootNode = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(exceptionMapperJson);

        var exceptionNode = rootNode.ExceptionMappers.FirstOrDefault(e => e.ExceptionName.Equals(exceptionName));
        var exceptionObject = Type.GetType(exceptionName);

        if (exceptionNode != null)
        {
            // Here I need the exception from the string value
            Policy.Handle<TimeoutException>().Retry().Execute(action);
        }
        else
        {
            // No Policy applied
            Policy.NoOp().Execute(action);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use reflection to call a generic method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232535/how-do-i-use-reflection-to-call-a-generic-method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per @thehennyy 's comment, [Jon Skeet's answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/232621/) covers how to use reflection to invoke a generic method when the generic type is known only at runtime.  The slight difference from the linked answer: because `.Handle<TException>()` is a static method on `Policy`, pass `null` as the first argument to `MethodInfo.Invoke()`.

Alternatively, because [Polly offers Handle clauses which can take a predicate](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly#step-1--specify-the--exceptionsfaults-you-want-the-policy-to-handle), you could simply:

```
var exceptionType = Type.GetType(exceptionName);
if (exceptionNode != null)
{
    Policy.Handle<Exception>(e => exceptionType.IsAssignableFrom(e.GetType())) // etc
}
```

This [live dotnetfiddle example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/U3fvLk) demonstrates it working.

---

Or, make your wrapper method itself generic:

```
public void Execute<TException>(Action action) where TExecption : Exception
{
    // reverses the approach: 
    // you'll want a typeof(TException).Name, to get the string name of the exception from TException

    // Then you can just Policy.Handle<TException>(...) when you construct the policy
}
```

---

As another refinement, you could consider constructing the policies only once at startup, and placing them in [`PolicyRegistry`](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/PolicyRegistry)